# Why use "will" instead of "would" in this case

Tags: grammar, indirect-speech

My teacher of Grammar at university told us that when we report a speech that was said in the past, we replace "will" by "would". However, in this example, she used "will" in the reported speech as well.
Here is the example:
"He won't come on time," she said.
--> She didn't think he will come on time.
Can someone explain please?

Comment: There can be licensing (possibly forcing) context: "He won't come on time," she said yesterday about Dave's planned visit on Friday. --> _She didn't think he will come on time._ (She might have changed her mind by now.) This makes the deleted form   "He won't come on time," she said. --> _She didn't think he will come on time._ correct.   But 'would' is far more likely to be correct.

Comment: Ask your professor. Sometimes humans slip up. And sometimes teachers deliberately say something "wrong" to see if anyone listened, noticed or cared.